# Minimize sum of product of series, given constraints

Tags: optimization

Given a series $x_t$ and constants $c_1$, $c_2$, I want to find another series $y_t$ such that  $\sum_t x_t \cdot  y_t$ is minimized, and

$\begin{cases}
  0 < \sum_s y_s < c_1 \text{ for all } s \in 0..t\\
  -c_2 < y_t < c_2
\end{cases}$

What kind of mathematics do I need to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your strict inequalities to weak inequalities, this is a *linear programming* problem.